# No Class Def Found Error in my JSP file

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I have a jsp file called AddBidding.jsp which adds bids for a facility. I am using the Google App Engine's datastore (objectify). When I try to run the file using `localhost:8888/AddBidding.jsp`. However, it keeps giving me `NoClassDefinitionFound` Error. Can I know what causes this error? I know it's due to the classpath but how do I fix it in Eclipse GAE?

Comment: Do you have this problem locally or on  AppEngine? What calls can not be found? Can you list a content of WEB-INF/lib?

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions over here since there are not too many details about which class is giving you the `NoClassDefFound` Error. Just ensure that all the external(additional) JARs that you use are present in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder also. For e.g. put all the Objectify and dependent JARs in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the Project on Project Explorer View > "Configure Build Path"

- In Source [tab] Make sure your Default output folder is right
- In Libraries [tab]  you have Web App Libraries

  - If not Add Library...

That should get you working.